# Dividing a string into 3 parts and export to CSV in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, export-to-csv

I have a string "**1 kg potatoes**" whereas **1** is the quantity, **kg** is the unit and **potatoes** is the item. I want that the compiler will read a string and match with "unit_list  & quantity_list"(see code below). And it saves the results into 3 columns in a CSV file.

```
   List<String> unit_list = Arrays.asList("g", "kg","ml","l");          
   List<String> quantity_list = Arrays.asList("Full", "Quarter", "Half", "3 Quarter", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   String input = "1 kg potatoes";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                            
   if (unit_list.equals(input)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
       System.out.println("Unit Detected");                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   }  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   if (quantity_list.equals(input)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       System.out.println("Quantity Detected");                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   }
```

> Expected Output in CSV File
>
> **Quantity, Unit, Item**
>
> 1, kg , potatoes

But this is not working for me. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Is order guaranteed in the input? Will it always be <unit> <quantity> <item> ? And if so, will the items always be valid, or do we need to check if quantity is outside the range, or the item does not exist, etc?

Comment: @djharten 
i. We don't need to check either item outside or not. We just need to separate the unit and quantity. Rest of everything is stored as <item>
ii.The order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: You need to put more focus on your question; otherwise, I'm afraid your question may be closed. After going through your comments posted on the answers, it is not clear whether you want to limit your units to `g`, `kg`, `ml` and `l` or it can be anything. Also whether there should be any space between qty and unit e.g. `2 g` or `2g`. These are just some of the things which came to my mind on the first glance but there can be many other important things you need to clarify when you ask a question.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash sir I have data which I need to divide into 3 columns.
In the data, some items have values "100g juice" and some with "10 g potatoes".
 Is this make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Based on the fact that you said something like "8 g carrots" could be "8g carrots" I've updated the original code and added a new method to the bottom.

Here's the solution I came up with. Since you said order is not guaranteed, and we don't need to check if the "item" is valid, I did it this way:

```java
  public static void parseToCSV() throws IOException {
    List<String> list = generateList();
    List<String> unitList = Arrays.asList("g", "kg","ml","l");          
    List<String> quantityList = Arrays.asList("Full", "Quarter", "Half", "3 Quarter", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");                                                                                                   

    for(String s : list) {
      String[] strArr = s.split(" ");
      // Checks if the String array is too short for what we need(i.e "8g carrots" instead of "8 g carrots")
      if(strArr.length == 2) {
        String newStr = rewriteString(strArr, quantityList);
        strArr = newStr.split(" ");
      }
      String[] itemLine = new String[3];
      for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        String str = strArr[i];
        int index = findValueLocation(str, quantityList, unitList);
        itemLine[index] = str;
      }
      String line = createLineForCSV(itemLine);
      writeToFile(line);
    }

  }

  private static List<String> generateList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String inputOne = "1 kg potatoes";
    String inputTwo = "3 g juice";
    String inputThree = "8g carrots";
    list.add(inputOne);
    list.add(inputTwo);
    list.add(inputThree);
    return list;
  }

  /**
   * Return the index where the value should go in a comma separated String. If the
   * value is not found in either list then it is the item by default.
   */
  private static int findValueLocation(String str, List<String> quantityList, List<String> unitList) {                                                                                                 

    for(String quantity : quantityList) {
      if(quantity.equals(str)) {
        return 0;
      }
    }
    for(String unit : unitList) {
      if(unit.equals(str)) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    return 2;
  }

  private static String createLineForCSV(String[] itemLine) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(itemLine[0]).append(",");
    sb.append(itemLine[1]).append(",");
    sb.append(itemLine[2]);
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static void writeToFile(String line) throws IOException {
    // Set to true for append mode
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("csv_file.csv", true));
    writer.write(line);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
  }
```

This works when I tested it. The only thing is it will always append to the CSV file every time you run it. If you want an option to clear the file so you can write all the data fresh then you could just add this method:

```java
  private static void clearFile() throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("csv_file.csv", false);
    writer.write("");
    writer.close();
  }
```

EDIT: New method to fix issue of "8g" instead of "8 g". What this does is check if the split String has length of 2. If so then it is not separated properly. We check the quantityList, since it should never come as "g8 carrots". We find the quantity, and create a new string of  and return that as the properly made String. Kind of a hacky solution, but it works for me.

```java
  private static String rewriteString(String[] arr, List<String> quantityList) {
    String strOne = arr[0];
    String strTwo = arr[1];
    String newStr = "";
    for(String quantity : quantityList) {
      if(strOne.contains(quantity)) {
        // 8g carrots becomes "8 g carrots"
        newStr = quantity + " " + strOne.substring(quantity.length()) + " " + strTwo;
        break;
      } else if(strTwo.contains(quantity)) {
        newStr = quantity + " " + strTwo.substring(quantity.length()) + " " + strOne;
        break;
      }
    }
    return newStr;
  }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: When I have entered "100 kg potatoes" this is storing "null,kg,potatoes" instead. I want to make it generic that the integer will readout from string and go to quantity. It might be 2*100g potatoes thus 2*100 will store in quantity. Can you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: Updated with new code based on that. Don't use "2*100", because that's not in the quantity list you gave me. I used "8" since it was in there. If you want to test "2*100" then add it to the quantityList :)

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting a null when you enter "100 kg potatoes" is because you don't have "100" in your quantityList that you posted at the top. If you don't want to use a list and make it generic, then attempt to parse each index as an Integer. If it comes back as true then boom, there's your quantity. But if you're looking for something like 2*100 that will be much more difficult and will involve more parsing. A thought would be find "unit" first, then determine if a value has any integer value in it, if so then the other one is "item" and you can go from there.

Comment: The problem of "80g" and "8 g" is resolved .thanks for that @djharten.
Another thing is that I don't want to make a list of quantity. Please make it generic.

Comment: can we achieve this goal that compiler read the input string and do the following.
i) integer in the **inputString** to **Quantity**
ii) check the units with the pre-defined list of units and add to **units**
ii) store the rest of all string as an **item**? including space

Comment: I'll let you work on making the quantity generic, but since there are so many possibilities(80x2, 100-200, 4x25, etc) it could involve a lot of parsing. The better idea would probably be to create a persistent database/list of all "units" and all "items", then by process of elimination you can set the last one as "quantity".

Comment: sir I have used some regular expression in the method **findValueLocation()** and your code works for me. Thank you for this.
Kindly update your code a little bit. I want to read the input from a **CSV file** that has data in a single column and then we perform our further processing on it by using your code.